# Waterproof Long Distance Wireless Shutter Release?

Tags: shutter-release, canon-6d, wireless

Hi I am a snowboarder looking for a reliable long distance shutter release for canon 6d ... I will be using while snowboarding so has to be good in cold and snowy conditions and very reliable ... Definitely willing to spend extra for a quality remote ... Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: How far is "long distance"?

Comment: @Andy Blankertz - up to 100 meters preferably

Comment: You're going to need a radio release rather than IR. Something like: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/749996-REG/Vello_RW_C2_FreeWave_Wireless_Remote_Shutter.html . As for waterproofing, a ziploc bag will work wonders! Or you could get a pouch designed for using cameras/phones underwater.

Comment: Thanks @ElendilTheTall for the suggestions ... Ill look into that remote and also like the ideas for waterproofing

Comment: Do you happen to know the dimensions to the remote and antenna? @ElendilTheTall Thanks

Comment: My only concern would be the antenna possibly freezing from the cold and snow and not functioning correctly?

Comment: Dimensions are on the B&H site under the specifications tab. I'm not sure what the operating temperature range is. You might have to do a bit of insulation work - wrap it in cotton wool :)

Comment: @jsnow if you take a look at the manufacturer site they have quite a range of radio triggers - the first one I clicked has an operating range of -20°C to 50°C. http://www.vellogear.com/listing?category=17772

Answer (score 1):

One of the interesting things about the Canon EOS 6D is that it sports built-in Wifi, and you can use that along with a smartphone and the [EOS Remote app](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/EOS_app) to control the camera. You're going to have somewhat limited range if you have the camera act as the access point, but you can also have the camera connect to an existing Wifi network. That means that you can use any available Wifi access point to increase the range of the smartphone "remote". The app does more than just work as a remote shutter release -- you can adjust settings like focus, shutter speed, aperture, etc., and you can see the "live view" image.

Assuming you already have a compatible smartphone (requires iOS or Android), EOS Remote is surely the cheapest option since the app is free. Certainly worth a try.